# Display PHP Array On New Line

Tags: php

I am trying to display the output of a sql query on 3 different lines using the echo function. The php code is enclosed inside a div tag. My code is below

```
<div class="ClientAdress" id="ClientAdress">
<?php
$db = new SQLite3( 'Stock_Control.sqlite');
$sql = 'SELECT City,County,Street_Adress FROM Customer WHERE Customer_ID = 14';
$result = $db->query($sql);//->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC); 

    $row = array(); 

    $i = 0; 

     while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){ 

         if(!isset($res['City'])) continue; 
          $row[$i]['City'] = $res['City']; 
          $row[$i]['County'] = $res['County']; 
          $row[$i]['Street_Adress'] = $res['Street_Adress']; 

          $i++; 

      } 

        echo $row[0]['City'];
        echo $row[0]['County'];
        echo $row[0]['Street_Adress'];

?>
</p>
</div>
```

The current output is "BurgasBurgasplaces"

---

**Edit:**

This is what I tried:

```
<div class="ClientAdress" id="ClientAdress">
<?php
$db = new SQLite3( 'Stock_Control.sqlite');
$sql = 'SELECT City,County,Street_Adress FROM Customer WHERE Customer_ID = 14';
$result = $db->query($sql);//->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC); 
$row = array(); 
$i = 0; 
while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{ 
if(!isset($res['City'])) continue; 
$row[$i]['City'] = $res['City']; 
$row[$i]['County'] = $res['County']; 
$row[$i]['Street_Adress'] = $res['Street_Adress']; 
$i++; 

} 
echo $row[0]['City'] .  "<br />\n";;
echo $row[0]['County'] .  "<br />\n";;
echo $row[0]['Street_Adress'] .  "<br />\n";;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: how would i display the echo function on a new line

Comment: What.. `echo $row[0]['City'].'<br>';`?

Comment: **sidenote:** you dont open that `p` tag, or your opening it in the wrong place

Comment: You have an answer/solution below. Been there for a while, actually.

Comment: You need to remove the extra semi-colon at the end of your echo lines -  `;;` should be `;`.

Comment: @Root0x I've made an edit to your question, "adding" what you tried. Code shouldn't be overwitten from the original post, but to "add" under the original post and "marked" as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate a line break to each one -

```
echo $row[0]['City'] . "<br />" . "\n";
echo $row[0]['County'] . "<br />" . "\n";
echo $row[0]['Street_Adress'] . "<br />" . "\n";
```

Using `\n` to produce clean HTML in source.

You can also use the following, having both `<br />` and `\n` inside one set of quotes:

```
echo $row[0]['City'] . "<br />\n";
echo $row[0]['County'] . "<br />\n";
echo $row[0]['Street_Adress'] . "<br />\n";
```

Otherwise, and should you later decide to add styling to those or wrapped in table tags, will all be inside one long line, rather than having each line neatly placed one underneath the other.

Comment: It's a simple as that *Sam* ;-)

Comment: You know me, I am such a simple guy @Fred-ii- ;-)

Comment: Hmmmm, interesting @Fred-ii-, I would have put both items in a single set of quotes.

Comment: Single quotes? Surely you don't mean `. '\n'`

Comment: No! `"<br />\n"` heh. A *single set* not *single quotes*

Comment: Ah.... yes you're right. Good point. Oh well, the OP's got enough to go on now ;-) Just force of habit.

Comment: Added my extra 2 cents *Sam!* ;-)

Comment: It's worth *thousands Ralph*! ;-)

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it is printing all of them on the same line at the same time.

Comment: Update your original post with your new code. Then we can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks ugly, simplify it even more;

```
foreach ($row[0] as $key => $value)
{
  printf('%s => %s <br>\n', $key, $value);
  // OR
  echo "$key => $value <br> \n";
}
```

Automating will help you make your code cleaner, easier to understand and make you program faster.